# How can I get name of the user executing my Perl script?

Tags: linux, perl

I have a script that needs to know what username it is run from.

When I run it from shell, I can easily use $ENV{"USER"}, which is provided by bash.

But apparently - then the same script is run from cron, also via bash - $ENV{"USER"} is not defined.

Of course, I can:

```
my $username = getpwuid( $< );
```

But it doesn't look nice - is there any better/nicer way? It doesn't have to be system-independent, as the script is for my personal use, and will be only run on Linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

crontab sets `$LOGNAME` so you can use `$ENV{"LOGNAME"}`. `$LOGNAME` is also set in my environment by default (haven't looked where it gets set though) so you might be able to use only `$LOGNAME` instead of `$USER`.

Although I agree with hacker, don't know what's wrong about `getpwuid`.

Answer (score 58):

Try getting your answer from several places, first one wins:

```
my $username = $ENV{LOGNAME} || $ENV{USER} || getpwuid($<);
```

Answer (score 10):

Does this look prettier?

```
use English qw( −no_match_vars );

my $username = getpwuid $UID;
```

Comment: Heh. In my actual code, I (of course) use English, and I actually use $REAL_USER_ID, but I didn't want to spark any "English vs. Short-names" debate in here :)

Comment: In my code I would use `$<`, so that isn't a debate I care about, but I thought you might consider it prettier.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, why doesn't that "look nice"?  That's the appropriate system call to use.  If you're wanting an external program to invoke (e.g. something you could use from a bash script too), there are the tools /usr/bin/id and /usr/bin/whoami for use.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently much has changed in Perl in recent years, because some of the answers given here do *not* work for fetching a clean version of "current username" in modern Perl.

For example, getpwuid($<) prints a whole bunch of stuff (as a list in list context, or pasted-together as a string in scalar context), *not* just the username, so you have to use (getpwuid($<))[0] instead if you want a clean version of the username.

Also, I'm surprised no one mentioned getlogin(), though that doesn't always work. For best chance of actually getting the username, I suggest:

```
my $username = getlogin() || (getpwuid($<))[0] || $ENV{LOGNAME} || $ENV{USER};
```